# How to compare a list to another list in LISP and avoid an EVAL error due to an undefined variable?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am trying to compare two lists in common lisp and then print "ROBOT ROBBIE" if they match. One of the inputs is a list given by the user (stored in wff) and the other input is a list from a list of lists called "nums". However, when I run my code I get the following error:

```
- EVAL: undefined function X
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix this? I have attached my code below for reference:

```
(defun same-elements (l1 l2)
  (and (subsetp l1 l2) (subsetp l2 l1)))


(defun answer-ynq()
;;;Defining the hash-table

  (setq nums '(13 15 19 33))
  (setq numsstuff '())

  (setq nums  (loop for i below 2
            collect (loop for e in '(Robot Robbie)
                  for j from 0
                  when (equal i j) collect '- else collect e)))
  (print nums)

  (print "Hello, please enter a command")
  (setq wff (read-delimited-list #\~))
  (terpri)
  (loop for x in nums
    do (if (same-elements (x wff))
                  (print "(ROBOT ROBBIE)")

                  ))

)


  (answer-ynq)
```

Comment: What is the syntax of function call in Lisp?

Comment: you should use always `let` where you use `setq`

Comment: I am always happy seeing new people learning CL but you should consider to spend some time to study the excellent resources give e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/common-lisp/info). Get used to CL's syntax and style and you will understand the error messages yourself. For all other questions you will find great feedback here.

Comment: `(x wff)` is a a function call. Function X called with argument WFF. Is `X` a function?

Comment: The error is not about an undefined variable (see the title of your question), but about an undefined function (see the error message).